# "$a, b$" vs. "$a$, $b$"

Tags: math-mode, spacing, best-practices

I have two questions.

1. Would you use `Let $x, y$ and $z$ be real numbers.` or `Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be real numbers.` ?
   Which one is better?
2. Would you use `For $x, y\in\mathbb R$ we have ...` or `For $x$, $y\in\mathbb R$ we have ...` ? 
   Which one is better?

Comment: Why does my text is only sometimes in code-mode when typing 4 spaces?

Comment: I would use `$x$, $y$, and $z$` and `$x, y \in \R$`.

Comment: I edited to use inline code, which is easyer to read in your case, but as a general comment, for your text to appear as code when you insert 4 spaces before, it also needs to be preceeded by an empty line.

Comment: I say 2nd choice: `$x$, $y$ and $z$`, sine it is Englishy text.  I use the first choice for `$f(x,y)$`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245675/a-b-and-c-vs-a-b-and-c

Comment: Regarding the first question: The second option is the correct one. In the sentence "Let *x*, *y* and *z* be real numbers," `x`, `y` and `z` fulfill the same syntactic roles as `Tom`, `Dick` and `Harry` do in the sentence "Let Tom, Dick and Harry be adult males." The fact that `x`, `y` and `z` are mathematical formulas and are entered using `$` symbols is secondary. In consequence, the commas should *not* be included in the math-mode material.

Comment: @SamuelAlbert I think that the problem with formatting was that when you want to use code into a list you have to indent 8 spaces --- 4 for the "list item" and 4 for the "code".

Answer (score 5):

I think you have asked several questions.

The first is about $x, y$ versus $x$, $y$. I think the second one is semantically and hence typographically right since the comma is not part of the mathematical expression. Your second example is a little ambiguous. There I would include the comma in the mathematics.

An implicit question is the choice between

> Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers

and

> Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$

That's a question of style. I find words easier to read than symbols, but your taste may differ.