# $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$ vs. $x_1$, $\dots$, $x_n$

Tags: math-mode, spacing, punctuation, best-practices

For example, if I want to say something like

> Let x_1, ..., x_n be real numbers.

should I use

```
Let $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$ be real numbers.
```

or

```
Let $x_1$, $\dots$, $x_n$ be real numbers.
```

Note that if one lists only two objects a, b, then

```
Let $a$, $b$ be real numbers.
```

should be used instead of something like

```
Let $a, b$ be real numbers.
```

since the comma is part of the text (and not of the mathematical notation), see ["$a, b$" vs. "$a$, $b$"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305577/a-b-vs-a-b) or [$a,\ b$, and $c$ vs. $a$, $b$, and $c$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245675/a-b-and-c-vs-a-b-and-c?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Use `\dots`; `\dotsc` is necessary in cases such as `a_1,a_2,\dotsc` where the nature of the dots cannot be determined by examining the next token.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122491/4427

Comment: `Let $x_1$, $\dots$, $x_n$ be real numbers.` seems needlessly complicated, but I can see where you are coming from...

Answer (score 4):

This is partly a math question and partly a tex question.

The expression represents a continuum, so the spaces around the dots should be uniform between the commas. This will be accomplished only by including the entire expression in a single math environment.

Now for the tex part. This is best expressed as `$x_1, \dots, x_n$`.  `\dotsc` isn't needed because it's possible to determine the position -- which should be on the line -- from the enclosing commas (as mentioned in a comment by @egreg).

Finally, althougn this won't break by itself if it happens to fall at the end of a line and will overflow into the margin, that can be remedied by inserting `\allowbreak` after whichever of the commas will result in the most satisfactory realignment of the paragraph.

Comment: @dexteritas Please read the note at the end of barbara's profile. The "wrong" spelling was intended.

Comment: @campa Okay, I didn't know that. Nevertheless, I think that a correct spelling is appropriate on this page. Otherwise every user could think of his own semantic meaning for correct and wrong spelling, then it becomes confusing ;)
Instead, if necessary, I would include the hint that it is only one's own opinion in the text.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should write "Let $x_1$, \dots, $x_n$ be real numbers." Two or many, in a text context they should be treated accordingly.

Comment: while breaking up the math string is quite acceptable if there are only two non-dots elements, the presence of the dots makes this a bad idea.  breaking up the math is okay in a string such as `if $a$, $b$, or $c$`, where uniformity of spacing isn't a consideration.