# how to render angle brackets with less spacing?

Tags: symbols

this code

```
$X = <X_1 ...,X_n>$
```

gives

[image]

how to have angle brackets render like this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
$X = \langle X_1, \dots, X_n \rangle$
```

Comment: @whnlp `<` and `>` in math mode are regular relational symbols. You must use `\langle` and `\rangle`, respectively.

Comment: It is very useful to use `\ldots` instead of `...` Regards.

Comment: Or even (semantically) better: `\dotsc` (AMS) for "dots after comma".

Comment: @ivankokan In this example `\dots` can be used, instead of `\dotsc`; the result is the same in this case. See [$x_1, \dotsc, x_n$ vs. $x_1$, $\dots$, $x_n$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445909/x-1-dotsc-x-n-vs-x-1-dots-x-n). Also for `\dotsc` the package `amsmath` is needed.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122491/difference-of-the-dots for a comparison of the \dots* variants

Answer (score 1):

Another option it is to use `bracket` package. Here I'm putting a MWE with the fonts `newtxtext` (Times New Roman) for the text and `newtxmath` for mathematical symbols of your image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\[X=\braket{X_1,\ldots,X_n}\]
\blindtext
\end{document}
```