# $a$, $b$ in $M$

Tags: math-mode, typography

Mathematicians often use

```
$a, b\in M$
```

to announce that a and b are elements of the set M.

Sometimes, one wants to replace the "\in"-symbol by the English word "in" – for example when one tries to reduce the usage of symbols in order to improve readability.

Question: Would you use

```
Let $a, b$ in $M$
```

or

```
Let $a$, $b$ in $M$
```

?

Comment: Let $a$, $b$ in $M$.

Comment: In either case, use $M$.

Comment: Karlo: Yes, I meant that. Just edited the question. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I'd use $a,b$ in $M$. I think this is off topic though.

Comment: Jérôme: Thanks. In fact I think that you can post this comment as an answer, maybe adding a short explanation.

Comment: @Hugh: If so, then excuse me. I thought this forum is more appropriate than math.SE or mathoverflow.SE.

Comment: It is the most appropriate site and it's just barely off topic. But both are syntactically valid LaTeX. They have different appearances but I think it's a matter of opinion which one is best. No apology necessary.

Comment: Related: [$a,\ b$, and $c$ vs. $a$, $b$, and $c$](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245675/a-b-and-c-vs-a-b-and-c/)

Comment: Let `$a$` and `$b$` be members of `$M$`. Let `$a$` and `$b$` be in $M$`.

Comment: Most LaTeX user know that `$a$, $b$` and `$a,b$` are not typeset the same. I cannot see why this question is put _off-topic._